# Custom Button not stretching with Flex when it is residing inside a Form

Tags: css, flexbox, svelte

I am having difficulty sizing a button placed within a form. There are 4 buttons and the 3rd button is inside of a form. All the buttons except this 3rd one is sizing according to the css.

```
<div class="topButtons">
        <FunButton size="medium" on:click={() => showSearchModal()}>Search</FunButton>

        <FunButton size="medium">
            <UploadMedia />
        </FunButton>

        <form action="?/delete" method="post" >
            <FunButton size="medium" color={'red'}>Delete media</FunButton>
        </form>

        <FunButton size="medium" on:click={() => goto('/app/check')}>Return</FunButton>
</div>
```

this is the css to lay them out with Flex;

```
.topButtons {
        grid-area: topButtons;
        display: flex;
        gap: 8px;
    }
```

The 3rd button does not stretch to take up the necessary width, how can this be fixed?

I am using `Svelte`, and these buttons `FunButton` are custom components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex box only applies to direct children, you can try "skipping" the form via:

```css
form { display: contents; }
```